# A book I read about a girl whose paintings could make the future happen

Tags: story-identification, books

About six years ago (but probably the book itself is older) I read a book for children (probably but not surely), fantasy genre. I read it in Italian, but think the original language was Spanish since every page had a counterpart page in Spanish.

That’s the plot: there is a girl in an orphanage, who was left here by her mother. She discovers that the paintings she draws can make things happen. She has a deaf (male) friend: once she draws a picture in which her friend moves because he hears that a heavy thing is going to fall from a high place (maybe a crane?). When this happens her friend doesn’t move, but from that he gradually gain/regain hearing but, after healing, he goes away (maybe he was adopted, I’m not sure). She is angry for that, so she paints a picture in which she is with her mother because she wants to go away, but during the night the paint changes and becomes different.  After some years the girl leaves the orphanage and goes working away. Then the old miss director is too old and dies, so she takes her position. In the final scene these is she, holding between her arms a little, very ill, girl, telling her she’s recognised what is happening, and this is the painting that changed in that long-passed night, and because of this she is sure the child won’t die.

Can anyone tell me if you have recognised this book? Have you got any idea about what the title may be? Please, it’s very important for me. If you have any question, I’ll be very happy to give you any answer you would need. Thanks

Comment: Can you remember any of the characters names?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I've written in the answer all I could remember.

Comment: Was this novel-length, a picture book, a short story?

Comment: A novel, not very long, but definetively a novel.

Comment: Fear Chloe, is an episode from Doctor Who, which has similar premise. maybe further research into this could reveal the original story?

Comment: You may try looking at the works mentioned in TVTROPES WARNING (don't look unless you want to lose the rest of your day) http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtInitiatesLife

Comment: I'm absolutelly sure it was a book, not a film or a movie or something so. And it wasn't part of a series.

Comment: I've been trying to find this, but without much success. I would add that if we can't find this, you might trying joining the [Italian SE](http://italian.stackexchange.com/) and getting to 20 rep, then asking about it in chat. Sure, the people there might not know SFF as well as we do, but on the other hand, they do know Italian.

Comment: who is the author of the book then i might be able to find out?

Comment: @bob: :) That's probably part of what they're looking for.

Comment: I don't know the autor, only the language and the plot. I'm sorry I can't add more, but that's what I remember.