# A magical pen or marker that what is drawn with comes to life

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

I recall that it was a boy and a pen falls from the sky. I think he draws a fish and it comes to life and jumps into the river or pond. He takes it home and has a blue wall in his room and he draws a hippo, and it comes to life. I just recall that they lived in a fishing town and lived by the bay or something like that.  It was a 80s or early 90's movie

Comment: lol. Solved here; https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/2eg37i/tomt_moviemovie_where_a_magical_pen_falls_from/ but not. Apparently it was a 1983 film that was a remake.

Comment: There's a [short story by Elizabeth Kay](http://www.elizabethkay.co.uk/magic/magic1.html) and a [Doctor Who episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_Her) which are about kids drawing pictures that come to life, but both of them have *girl* protagonists, so not what you're looking for.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/181408/4918 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125190/4918 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/143741/4918 for other stories about drawings that come to life. In general, see TVTROPES WARNING http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtInitiatesLife for a list of stories with such an element.

Comment: To add on to @b_jonas list for anyone else who comes across this question looking for similar stuff, one currently not mentioned in the TVTropes list is *Mahō no Pen* ("The Magic Pen") a 1946 11-minute short film by Kumagawa Masao.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plot seems similar to Otto is a Rhino (1983).

> Topper is an optimistic young boy with a vivid imagination. He is also in love with Cilla, but she thinks he's very crazy. One day Topper finds a pencil and draws a rhino that comes to live! This changes everything.

Comment: Is that a film, or is there a book version too?

Comment: It's both apparently

Comment: It is Otto is a Rhino. I just had the wrong animal. Thanks!